# Validating uniqueness scoped to range of attribute values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, enums

I am writing an invitation system, where invitations can have 1 of 4 states:

```
enum state: [:pending, :accepted, :rejected, :revoked]
```

I want to validate the uniqueness of the invitation email attribute, so that:
- invalid if pending and a pending or accepted invitation already exists
- valid if a rejected or revoked invitation exists

I have tried:

```
validates :email, uniqueness: { scope: :status }, if: -> { [:pending, :accepted].include?(status) }
```

However this still prevents a pending invitation from being created if a rejected invitation exists.

I know I can do this with a custom validation, but I was wondering if it was achievable with active record validations?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. It was the `conditions` option that I needed.

```
validates :email, uniqueness: { conditions: -> { where(status: [:pending, :accepted]) } }
```